# PyScripter crashes at "import processing"

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, pyscripter

I set up PyScripter latest version, 2.7) to work with QGIS (2.2, OSGeo4W install) following http://chelahmy.blogspot.ca/2011/02/setting-up-pyscripter-for-quantum-gis.html. It generally works well. I'm running Windows 7.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append("C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\python")
sys.path.append("C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins")
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from processing.core.Processing import Processing
```

I need the sys.path.append to import qgis properly (rather than setting them in the PYTHONPATH). However, when I run the line

```
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
```

PyScripter simply shuts down, no error message, window just closes. Has anybody else experienced this? Same thing happens with other imports, like

```
import processing
```

I can import all the other plugin libraries (GdalTools, fTools, db_manager) with no problems - but I don't need those, I need the proceesing library to access all the nice OTB tools.

Comment: I just tried running the same code in Eclipse (4.3.2, Aptana, PyDev). When I 'import processing' I get errors like "Can't load requested DLL: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll". Which is double weird because a) that path is not in my PYTHONPATH (but eve if I add it I get the same message) and b) the specified files are actually in that location.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by running a few lines of code before "import processing".

First I created an (unused) application object. "processing" won't work without it and pyscripter will crash.

```
app = QgsApplication([], True)
```

Then I "manually" initialized Processing.

```
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
```

Not only did the absence of these last two lines cause pyscripter to crash, but I couldn't access the processing algorithms in any environment (not just pyscripter) without them.