# Getting QGIS python modules to work from PyScripter in Windows 10?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, installation, pyscripter, windows-10

Been trying lots of "solutions" from net research but nothing seems to work.

I have the current versions of QGIS from OSGEO and PyScripter 2.5

Based on one of the solutions I tried...

```
import sys
sys.path.extend([r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python",r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin"])
sys.path.reverse()
import qgis.core
```

gives me

> Message   File Name   Line    Position     Traceback
>            4
>         C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis__init__.py  26       ImportError: No module named sip

```
import processing
```

gives me

> ImportError: No module named processing

and path is

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\; C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
```

pythonpath includes

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python
```

Tried "solutions"

1. https://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/configure-pyscripter-qgis/
2. [How can I Setup Python to recognize QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45473/how-can-i-setup-python-to-recognize-qgis)
   (and links from it)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297391/problems-while-importing-pyqgis-modules-in-python
4. [Import error for qgis.core when running OSGeo4w shell script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script)

and

[Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102)

after running the .bat in above I get "ImportError: no module name qgis.core" in python within osgeo shell as well.

Comment: What folders are in C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python and C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin? Look for a processing folder. Mine was in python\plugins, and try append the path to the folder using sys.path.append.

Comment: @AlexMcVittie I used "sys.path.extend([r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python",r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin", r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing"])" and then ran import qgis.core and now I get -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92069/pyscripter-crashes-at-import-processing/94451#94451)? I know it has been mentioned in the solutions you mentioned but perhaps you can try it again,

Comment: @Joseph I wish it did. I still get the same errors.

Comment: Little offtopic, but maybe useful - Pycharm GUI offers easy setting of project python interpreter, where you just find it and it will show which packages are available (can be downloaded) for that python distribution...

Comment: @DavidK , +1 I was literally typing a message along your comment, then I saw yours.

Comment: @yanes -I tried this but it still does not allow me to import pyQGIS or processing - I am having "memory" issues with a process in QGIS python and want to see how I can do this directly. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171114/memory-issue-qgis-python-processing-does-not-complete

Comment: If using extend it complains about the DLL, then it can't find the qgis DLLs which lies in the `qgis/bin` directory, this should be included in the system PATH variable not the PYTHONPATH. You have to `import os` and then `os.environ['PATH']='C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\bin;'+os.environ['PATH']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PYTHONHOME should be:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27
```

Your PATH should include (in the beggining):

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin; C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin
```

PYTHONPATH should have:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python27.zip
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
```

In code you have to:

```
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication(sys.argv, False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

If you don't have [sip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIP) in your Python installation you should install it.

### EDIT

Provided you are running the correct python version for pyqgis you can setup everything in python code:

```
import sys, os

os.environ['PATH'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\bin;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin;' + os.environ['PATH']
sys.path.extend(['C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages'])
```

Comment: thanks but I still get "ImportError: No module named qgis.core"

Comment: I can see only two sources for this problem: the PYTHONPATH for `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python` is wrong (check drive letter and OSGeo4W64 or OSGeo4W) or you have a bad QGIS installation (try to change the `curdir` to where `qgis\python` is and import, if you keep having the same error it is probably a bad installation).

Comment: If you have `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py` and `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py` there is no reason to get `No module named qgis.core` error. Assert you have these files and that PYTHONPATH is pointing to the right address of `qgis\python`. I could set up PyScripter with pyqgis successfully here. Don't forget to use Python 2.7, not Python 3.

Comment: -yes the path are correct. I now get a sip import error (DLL load failed). I have sip in C:\Python27\Lib\sip-4.17 is this correct? I just extracted the zip to this directory and ran sipconfig.py

Comment: Did you compile it? You have to compile it. Maybe you already have [Visual C++ 2008 64-bit Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). You have to use `nmake` and then `nmake install` to generate the "binaries", which is sip.pyd. Although I recommend you to use Python 27 from OSGeo4W, which already have an option to install sip with their installer, it is easier and less prone to error.

Comment: Great...I can now import qgis.core but I get {{>>> layer = QgsVectorLayer("E:\Junk\pt000349_contour.tab", "contour", "mapinfo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsVectorLayer' is not defined}} What's happened? thank you.

Comment: Have you imported `QgsVectorLayer`? `from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer` or use QgsVectorLayer with prefixes `qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer` or if you want to import everything from qgis.core do `from qgis.core import *`

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296985/creating-standalone-python-script-using-pyqgis/296994?noredirect=1#comment477279_296994 hi please help needed in a similar question'